# Did Apple kill iCloud Keychain wifi password sync?

Tags: icloud, wifi, keychain

Wi-Fi passwords used to sync between my devices via iCloud Keychain, a wifi password entered on my MacBook would end up on my phone via the 4G connection, and the phone would automatically connect, handy.

As of the last update this doesn’t happen, now I have to bring my phone next to my laptop and tap the share notification to pass it over Bluetooth to get the phone to connect, it’s slow, and half of the time doesn’t work.

Did Apple really scrap the iCloud sync solution to force everyone to use the Bluetooth one that is way more suited for sharing with friends rather than between my own devices?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118517/discussion-on-question-by-steve-did-apple-kill-icloud-keychain-wifi-password-syn).

Answer (score 2):

I bumped into this question when searching for the problem.

And I figured out iCloud didn't set up (or logged in) on my Mac OS X. When I logged in to icloud, KeyChain access created a new tab for iCloud just under the Login tab.

Please be sure, you set up iCloud on your Mac OS X.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208682

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Then I looked at the iCloud settings page on my mac and found out that Key chain syncing mysteriously have been unchecked. I checked it and now wifi password syncing seems to work again.

[image]